# Embed Composer into Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, composer-php

I am creating my own PHP Framework for learning purposes. It has also a plug in system. To manage these plug-ins (and other external libraries) I used Composer. My plug-ins are also composer packages that can be installed with Composer. But I want users to be able to install plugins with the command line (which they now can by doing 'composer require pluginname') and also with a interface. Is it possible to embed Composer in my framework so they can handle the plug-ins through the interface without the need to install composer?

PS. For more information about my framework see [my reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/4b9351/creating_own_php_framework_for_learning_purposes/)

Comment: composer is a php archive. "Installation" is just a copy of the file. If you want to use composer classes directly from your php application, you need to add [composer/composer](https://github.com/composer/composer) dependency to your composer.json

Answer (score 2):

To embed composer in your project, there is package [dflydev/dflydev-embedded-composer](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-embedded-composer).

It's used in [Sculpin](https://github.com/sculpin/sculpin). So it uses [`sculpin install`](https://github.com/sculpin/sculpin/blob/0a5489a37fb6d498985c23cca5fa42d176be8c99/bin/sculpin.php#L64) instead of `composer install`.

Comment: Can I require/install/update packages with that package in PHP code? So I want to be able to do composer require packagename, but not from the command line but in PHP code. If this is possible, then thanks! I find the documentation of this package not very clear though.. Does someone have a simpler example where this package is used?

Comment: I can't for example figure out how I would do a `composer require packagename` with that package..